# ASP.net Core MVC Login

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-core, web

I am making a website with ASP.net core MVC. I want the website just to have one admin login to manage a database that manages the layout of the page. How do I have only one use without Microsoft Identity that includes everything for a millon users. I just want to have one login for a user (me) to live edit a website layout via a database, everyone that visits the page should never have to login. Thanks beforehand!

/* UPDATE */

I have managed to successfully add a userprincipal to a user that logs in with the use of claims. I have a question: How do I safely store the passwords and how do I claim a password? What ClamType do I use for password validation?

Best regards Max

Comment: It's all the same - Microsoft Identity will still work. You will only have one user with whatever privileges you require.

Comment: Use ASP.NET Identity and add the `Authorize` attribute on the admin controller(s). It doesn't matter if you need one user or 100. You still need to strongly salt and hash the password, send SMS notifications, handle login/logout, password change etc.

Comment: The only problem I have with Identity is that its a bit "messy". Not in the part bad, just what I need is just a username and a password, and Identity has everything, email, phone etc.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection is part of the native libraries, at least if you do Windoze.  If you wanted to be _really_ cool you might want to use System.Data.IDbConnection instead, but that's a whole other SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! I used this tutorial on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fhfvbl_KbWo&t=1049s&ab_channel=RawCodingRawCoding)! It shows you have to use claims and use cookies, I made a special variant of it with sha256 + salt password encryption. Thanks everyone for your time and help!

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to implement and integrate a simple authentication and authorization mechanism in your ASP.NET Core MVC app without ASP.NET Core Identity, you can try to  implement and use a custom cookie-based authentication based on your actual requirement/scenario.

For more information about "Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity", please check:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0

And it shared an example app in above doc, you can refer to the sample code to achieve same in your app.

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/security/authentication/cookie/samples/3.x/CookieSample/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml.cs#L116

Answer (score 1):

This might help if you don't want to go for Microsoft.Identity.
You can have a separate route (for eg: /#/admins) This page will only be visible to the 'Admin' user.
Now, admin can be authenticated either via having one property for the user for Admin or by having different admin credentials.

Comment: And how does one identify this admin user? You seem to have missed the point of the question.